# Input field value working in one area and not in another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I am designing my website in ReactJS and I'm having an issue. The desktop version of the website works perfectly! The mobile version, however, has one problem: my input field claims to have no value! I'll post the code below, but basically the desktop version has the email signup in the toolbar at the top (this is where it works) and the mobile version has it in the sidedrawer, where my links are (doesn't work here).

App.js

```
 addEmailSub = () => {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    mailerlite.addSubscriber(104625980, email).then(() => {
      this.setState({isSubscribed: true});
    });
  }

  render() {
    var backdrop;

    if(this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
      backdrop = <Backdrop click={this.backdropClickHandler}/>;
    }
    return(
    
      <div>
        <Toolbar drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} addEmailSub={this.addEmailSub} isSubscribed={this.state.isSubscribed}/>
        <SideDrawer show={this.state.sideDrawerOpen} addEmailSub={this.addEmailSub} isSubscribed={this.state.isSubscribed}/>
        {backdrop}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/books" component={Books} />
          <Route path="/events" component={Events} />
          <Route path="*" component={About} />
          
        </Switch>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Toolbar.js (this is where the signup component works)

```
const toolbar = props => (
    <header className="toolbar">
        <nav className="toolbar-navigation">
            <div className="toolbar-toggle">
                <DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler}/>
            </div>
            <div className="toolbar-logo">
                <img className="logo" src={logo}></img>
            </div>
            <SocialMedia />            
            <div className="spacer" />
            <div className="signup">
                <Signup addEmailSub={props.addEmailSub} isSubscribed={props.isSubscribed}/> //this works
            </div>
            
            <div className="spacer" />
            <div className="toolbar-nav-items">
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/books">Books</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/events">Events</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
);
```

Sidedrawer.js

```
const sideDrawer = props => {
    var drawerClasses = 'side-drawer';
    if(props.show) {
        drawerClasses = 'side-drawer open';
    }
    
    return(
        <nav className={drawerClasses}>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/books">Books</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/events">Events</Link></li>
            </ul>
            <div className="side-drawer-signup">
                <Signup addEmailSub={props.addEmailSub} isSubscribed={props.isSubscribed}/> //this does not work
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
    
};
```

Signup.js

```
const signup = props => {
    if(props.isSubscribed) {
        return(<div>
            <h3 className="signup-thanks">Thanks for signing up! Check your email :)</h3>
        </div>)
    }
    else{
        return(<div>
                <input id="email" className="signup-input" placeholder="Enter your email address"></input>
                <button onClick={props.addEmailSub} className="signup-button">Beta Read!</button>
            </div>);
    }
}
```

Unless I forgot how to read, I am positive I passed down all the props and functions appropriately, but the Signup component in the Sidedrawer doesn't capture any form data. I posted on Reddit and have searched the first few pages of Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find anything pertaining to my exact issue: where the input field captures text in one spot but not the other.

EDIT:
Thanks to yjay, I got it working properly! They were correct, it was looking for the first input id of "email". I thought it would be treated as the same input box rendered in a different spot, but it actually treats it as two separate inputs. I will post how I fixed it here:

App.js

```
    addEmailSub = () => {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    if (!email) { //this checks if the first input box has no value
      email = document.getElementById("sidebar-email").value; //this tells the website to look at the other input box
    }
    console.log('value of email is: ' + email); //VINDICATION
    mailerlite.addSubscriber(104625980, email).then(() => {
      this.setState({isSubscribed: true});
    });
  }
```

Toolbar.js

```
<Signup inputID="email" addEmailSub={props.addEmailSub} isSubscribed={props.isSubscribed}/> //this is all I changed from above. Added inputID prop
```

Sidedrawer.js

```
<Signup inputID="sidebar-email" addEmailSub={props.addEmailSub} isSubscribed={props.isSubscribed}/> //this is all I changed here, just like toolbar, adding inputID as a prop with a different id
```

Signup.js

```
return(<div>
                <input id={props.inputID} className="signup-input" placeholder="Enter your email address"></input> //here I use the prop to dynamically change the id based on where it's being rendered
                <button onClick={props.addEmailSub} className="signup-button">Beta Read!</button>
            </div>);
```

Fixed just in time, thank you yjay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem you have two elements with same id "email". It makes your html invalid and it seems to force `getElementById`, which return one elem, to choose. My guess is it has chosen the one from Toolbar (prolly cause it's higher). I think you should show one of them conditionally or give them different IDs.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input! That's weird, the input field is the same, it just gets rendered in different places. Do you think it's always looking for the one in toolbar, even when it's not rendered?

Comment: If it's not in html there is nothing to look for ;) Using singup in two places creates two inputs with same id. Function getElementById can't work properly when IDs aren't unique.

Comment: Good morning! I'm going to implement the change you recommended now. I'll come back and edit this comment if I can get it to work. Thanks for your help!